# Im having an issue with an argument when I run in IDLE

Tags: python

My argument is as follows:

```
self.draw(self.pen, side, u0, v0, x, y);
```

For it to run it needs to be 6 arguments, but it is considering "self.pen" as 2. Why is it doing this and how can I make it read it correctly? Thanks

```
# A Mandelbrot patterns class:
class MandelbrotPatterns:
    # Initialize the pen, and determine the window width and height:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pen = turtle.Pen(); 
        self.width = self.pen.window_width();
        self.height = self.pen.window_height();

    # Given numbers self, u0, v0, and side, design a pattern:
    def mandelbrot(self, u0, v0, side):
        self.pen.tracer(False);   
        for x in range(-self.width/2, +self.width/2):
            for y in range (-self.height/2, +self.height/2):
                self.draw(self.pen, side, u0, v0, x, y);
            if (x % 20 == 0):
                self.pen.tracer(True); self.pen.tracer(False);
        self.pen.tracer(True);

    # Draw in color a pattern element at point (x, y):
    def draw(self, side, u0, v0, x, y):
        maxCount = 25;
        u = u0 + x * (side / 100.0);
        v = v0 - y * (side / 100.0);
        a = 0 ; b = 0; count = 0; 
        while (count < maxCount and a * a + b * b <= 4):
            count = count + 1;
            a1 = a * a - b * b + u;
            b1 = 2 * a * b + v;
            a = a1; b = b1;
        ez = float(count) / maxCount;
        color = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(ez, ez, ez);
        self.pen.color(color);
        self.pen.up(); self.pen.goto(x, y); self.pen.down();
        self.pen.forward(1);
```

Comment: Does your method definition include `self` as an argument?

Comment: Yes self is in other arguments.

Comment: In Python, semicolons at the end of the line are optional, and conventionally not included. While they don't do any harm, I'd remove them where not necessary, as it's against the style of most Python code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:

```
def draw(self, side, u0, v0, x, y)
```

You have no `pen` parameter. Try this:

```
def draw(self, pen, side, u0, v0, x, y)
```

Comment: Awesome thanks @Chad I couldnt figure out why this wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

It's not considering `self.pen` as 2, it's inserting `self` as the first argument. That's normal for all object method functions.

Your definition of `draw` doesn't have a `pen` argument, nor does it need one as you use `self.pen` whenever one is needed. Just drop it off the function call.

Comment: so should I just delete `self` from `self.pen`?

Comment: @user2510694, if you would give us the definition of `self.draw` I could be a little more specific.

Comment: I put up the entire function.

Answer (score 0):

how is self initialized? I'm assuming something along the lines of:

```
class Foo(object):
def __init__(self, pen):
    self.pen = pen

def draw(self, pen, side, u0, v0, x, y):
    return pen,side,u0,v0,x,y
```

if so, the following:

```
foo1 = Foo('ink pen')
bar = foo1.draw(foo1.pen, 'left','0','1','2','3')
```

should return:

`('ink pen', 'left', '0', '1', '2', '3')`

EDIT:
after your additional code was added above, it becomes clear that the issue is:

`def draw(self, side, u0, v0, x, y):`

it has no "pen" parameter.
You should update it to be:

`def draw(self, pen side, u0, v0, x, y):` as I listed above initially.

Comment: I have self initialized this way

Comment: {`def __init__(self):
        self.pen = turtle.Pen(); 
        self.width = self.pen.window_width();
        self.height = self.pen.window_height();`}

Comment: I put everything in the origianl post.